# Why does Core Data resurrect a deleted object when I delete a related object?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, ios5

Let's say I have a House entity in Core Data, and it is associated with many GraphicalAssets, which are pictures of the House.

I want to totally blow away all graphical assets for all houses, and the houses themselves. The delete behavior on the relationship, for both directions, is Nullify. It seems like the correct order to delete things is to blow away the graphical assets first, then the houses. Here's what happens:

```
NSFetchRequest* fetchAllGraphicalAssets = [ [ NSFetchRequest alloc ] initWithEntityName:@"GraphicalAsset" ];
NSArray* allGraphicalAssets = [ self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchAllGraphicalAssets error:nil ];
for( GraphicalAsset* asset in allGraphicalAssets )
        [ self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:asset ];
[ self.managedObjectContext processPendingChanges ];

// At this point, if I execute fetchAllGraphicalAssets again, the count is 0. Perfect.

NSFetchRequest* housesRequest = [ NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"House"];
NSArray* existingHouses = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest: housesRequest error:nil]; 
    for( House* house in existingHouses )
        [ self.managedObjectContext deleteObject: house ];
[ self.managedObjectContext processPendingChanges ];

// Now, if I execute fetchAllGraphicalAssets again, the count is > 0. What is going on?
```

So, it seems like, because houses used to point to the graphical assets (a relationship that should have been nullified when the assets were deleted), it magically resurrected the deleted objects when I delete the houses. Why is this happening? I have even tried explicitly nulling out the relationship between the houses and their graphical assets, in both directions, before deleting either object, and it still behaves this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete rule for the to-many relationship from `House` to `Graphic` should be cascade - this means deleting a `House` will cascade the delete to all the `Graphic` objects

Comment: If I keep the code I had to set the existing relationships to nil, changing to cascade has no effect. This makes sense. But it would also make sense for it to have no effect since 0 Graphical Assets exist at the time I start deleting houses, so there should be nothing to cascade to. Nonetheless, I removed the extra statements and I do get different behavior. When I eventually save the manage object context, though, it pegs my processor for eternity and never completes. This is the same behavior I got when I tried switching things up and deleting the houses before the graphical assets.

Comment: I'm going to accept this because it does prevent the behavior I described from happening. Though, it did not solve my problem (it wouldn't save at all) and I ended up having to rip out the relationship and do something different to accomplish what I needed. I think something was screwy with how the relationship was defined to begin with.